# SQL: Select Multiple Columns with Max() on calculated values

Tags: sql

Real basic:  I have table T with following data:

```
ID   StartDate  Term (months)
----------------------
1    10/1/2012   12
2    10/1/2012   24
3    12/1/2012   12
```

I need to know the ID of the row that has the max end date.  I've successfully calculated the end date as
select  max( DateAdd(month, term, StartDate) from table  [this would result in 10/1/2014]

how do i get the ID value and Start Date of the row that contains the max end date?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the platform and version of SQL. Efficient solutions to this problem are different on all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, StartDate
FROM T
ORDER BY DateAdd(month, term, StartDate) DESC
```

MySQL:

```
SELECT ID, StartDate
FROM T
ORDER BY DateAdd(month, term, StartDate) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In case more than one ID has the same extreme "end date" and you need them all, you can try this:

```
SELECT x.id
FROM (
   SELECT id
        , RANK ( ) OVER ( ORDER BY  DateAdd(month, term, StartDate) DESC) as rn
   FROM T
   ) x
WHERE t.rn = 1
```